# android disable webview bounces

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have set a `LinearLayout` with `admob` and `WebView`. 
When `admob` appears on top, `WebView Y pos` is properly repositioned to `0 + adMobHeight`.

Then if you touch and drag `WebView`, you are able to move vertially same admob height! This property on iOS is called `bounces`.

**How to deactivate it?**

If not possible, hot to force `WebView` to recalculate its size whitout reloading content? Thank you

Please note that scrolls are alreary disabled,

```
    webviewB.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webviewB.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to display on top of the screen then you may want to consider using RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
  android:id="@+id/ad" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:backgroundColor="#000000"
  app:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
  app:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
/>

<!-- WebView below that -->

<!--WebView-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: addMob is only displayed using linearLayout. If you try this configuration, admob is not displayed